# Tex-laden maths usage questions

Tags: discussion, migration

On meta.tex.sx, I've asked a question about a class of questions that might get asked over there (and have been) that are (i) ostensibly about maths usage, but (ii) might best be served by an answer that is primarily about how to handle the notation in Latex (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/where-usage-meets-tex ).

One of the moderators, Martin Scharrer, suggests that the best course of action for these is to migrate them here: this is the right place for the usage part, and there are many knowledgeable Texnicians over here who might be able to spot and handle the need for Latex-specific content in the answers.

Would this policy be acceptable here?

Comment: As less of a general comment than a specific one about the question linked to on the meta.tex post: I would agree with Martin that _that_ particular question fits on Maths more so than on TeX, mainly because it hardly has any TeX specific content aside from the use of the TeX notation to express mathematics. But that is somewhat different from the questions that you ostensibly asked about in this meta question here.

Comment: @WillieWong: To put the point another way, fine issues of math notation generally can be realised in Tex, and just looking at different ways of doing that can cast light on usage questions.  But I'm happy with migrating to here, since I think this site is pretty Tex-aware.

Answer (score 9):

If your question is overlapping the two disciplines, it may be best to split it into two distinct parts, and post these parts separately in the respective exchanges. Saying this, it is my opinion that the example in your meta post on the TeX exchange belonged solely here and not there, since no part of the question is about how to use LaTeX to get what you want.

If you were to get an answer here that suggests that you do something tricky in LaTeX (which I imagine would be unlikely) then you could post a question to the TeX exchange, linking your question here, pointing out the answer you liked and asking how to carry out the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this site is about mathematics, not about the tools that people use to write mathematics. If we're going to start answering LaTeX questions, then I hope that we will also answer questions about Microsoft Word, and Powerpoint, and give advice about the best pencils, paper, and chalk to use, too.

People who use LaTeX often need copious help, to be sure, but there are plenty of places to get it, and I hope this site doesn't become another one of them.

For similar reasons, I'm not keen on discussing Mathematica or Matlab usage here, either.

Comment: There seems to be a consensus that matlab questions are on topic at MSE, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/is-matlab-on-topic). Mathematica now has a separate site, but before that, this was the most appropriate place, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/questions-on-mathematica).

Comment: I am not sure, whether this is an example of a good question, but several chalk-related questions have been asked at MO, one of them has 85 upvotes at this moment: [Where to buy premium white chalk in the U.S., like they have at RIMS?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26267/where-to-buy-premium-white-chalk-in-the-u-s-like-they-have-at-rims)
and
[Good chalk in the UK](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58168/good-chalk-in-the-uk).

Comment: The FAQ says "We welcome questions about: ... Software that mathematicians use".  The Tex-SX site is much better able to deal with overt Latex questions, but I am not suggesting that these be migrated.

Comment: OK, so pencils, chalk and software are all in. Fair enough. I just didn't want this site to become yet another TeX-fest.